# Python library to output images as camera

Tags: windows, python, camera

I have a Python script / process that produces a series of images and I'm looking for a way to output those images to the OS (Windows in this case) as a camera device so that the images can be used in streaming applications that use a camera view, e.g. on Zoom or MS Teams. This would be similar to how the Snap Camera app works, but instead of filters applied to camera input I'd be piping in the images wholesale.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, there could be an indirect way to do that, but for this approach to work, you will need a part of the display (for example, one of the screens in a dual monitor setup) to be reserved.

Disclosure: The product discussed below is from the company I work for.

If it’s possible to have that part of display, here’s how this works:

1. Display the images you need to feed to the camera on that part of the screen at the times you wish them to appear in the video feed.
2. Use the [LEAD Screen Capture DirectShow](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v20/multimedia/filters/lead-screen-capture-filter-2-0.html) video source to capture the area where the images are displayed.
3. This DirectShow component appears as a standard camera device that can be used with various programs that support cameras.

If you would like to try this approach, you can download the free evaluation of the SDK that contains the screen capture filter [from this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm)